# Why does this POST request return a 405

Tags: ajax, laravel, http, post, get

I have a problem with a route. I declared the route as a post and the form has a post method,
but when I submit my form I get a `405` error. Also the allowed methods GET and HEAD. This is the AJAX call with the method post.

```
var form = $('#typeCreateForm');
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajaxSetup({headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}});
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "{{route('admin.type.store')}}",
                        data: form.serialize(),
                        success: function(data){
                            console.log(data);
}
});
```

Here is my route

```
// all routes name are prefixed with admin
Route::post('evenment/type/index/store','TypeController@store')->name('type.store');
```

Comment: Is your route name being prefixed with `admin.`?

Comment: yeah all the routes are prefixed with admin

Comment: how is your route presented in the command php artisan route:list

Comment: it has a post method in the route list

Comment: hmm... normally cross checking php artisan route:list with the network tab in the browser should do it, but right now we do not have the results of those two things. I think you need to include that for anyone to help you.